# Checagem de arquivo existente de maneira assíncrona

Tags: node.js

Meu código recebe escreve um arquivo, porém, precisa verificar se o arquivo já existe e, caso exista, renomeá-lo. É possível fazer isso sem usar o `fs.existsSync`?

Meu código atual:

```
fs.readFile(file.path, function (err, data) {

    for (i=2; !fs.existsSync(file.path); i++){
        file.name =file.name + i.toString();
        file.path = "./public/files/" + file.name;
    };
}

fs.writeFile(file.path, data, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.warn(err);
  }
  console.log("The file: " + file.name + " was saved as " + file.path);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Será que isso pode te ajudar? [Documentação](https://gist.github.com/joepie91/bbf495e044da043de2ba)

```
var fs = require("fs");
var Promise = require("bluebird");

function existsAsync(path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    fs.exists(path, function(exists){
      resolve(exists);
    })
  })
}
```

Ou então:

```
var path = require('path'); 

path.exists('foo.txt', function(exists) { 
  if (exists) { 
    // faça alguma coisa
  } 
}); 

// ou

if (path.existsSync('foo.txt')) { 
  // faça algo
}
```

> Para versões acima de Node.js v0.12.x

`path.exists` e`fs.exists` estão depreciados use `fs.stat`  :

```
fs.stat('foo.txt', function(err, stat) {
    if(err == null) {
        console.log('File exists');
    } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
        // file does not exist
        fs.writeFile('log.txt', 'Some log\n');
    } else {
        console.log('Some other error: ', err.code);
    }
});
```

espero ter conseguido te ajudar!